Two disks in mdadm but one has much higher aqu-sz, await, %util
I have two disks in an mdadm RAID1 array but (at times at least) they seem to be performing very differently from one another:
07:24:53 AM       tps     rkB/s     wkB/s     dkB/s   areq-sz    aqu-sz     await     %util DEV
07:25:03 AM     70.90   1382.40    577.65      0.00     27.65      1.54     21.67      8.99 sdc
07:25:03 AM     66.00   1382.40    540.85      0.00     29.14     11.13    168.66     90.52 sdd
07:25:03 AM    144.00      0.00    576.00      0.00      4.00     81.66    567.10     97.86 md0

As you can see, sdd has a far higher await and %util than sdc which is unsurprisingly dragging down the performance of the whole array.
The one other anomaly you will notice in the sar output above is that the rkB/s of the two drives is not reflected in the rkB/s of the array (md0).  These rkB/ss are due to a raid check being run at the time this sar sample was taken.
But back to the main point, what could be the cause of the huge imbalance of await and %util from these two drives?
This is what smartctl -a has to say about the drives:
sdc:
=== START OF INFORMATION SECTION ===
Model Family:     Western Digital Red (SMR)
Device Model:     WDC WD40EFAX-68JH4N1
Serial Number:    [redacted]
LU WWN Device Id: 5 0014ee 26982658a
Firmware Version: 83.00A83
User Capacity:    4,000,787,030,016 bytes [4.00 TB]
Sector Sizes:     512 bytes logical, 4096 bytes physical
Rotation Rate:    5400 rpm
Form Factor:      3.5 inches
Device is:        In smartctl database [for details use: -P show]
ATA Version is:   ACS-3 T13/2161-D revision 5
SATA Version is:  SATA 3.1, 6.0 Gb/s (current: 3.0 Gb/s)
Local Time is:    Wed Sep 11 07:52:18 2024 EDT
SMART support is: Available - device has SMART capability.
SMART support is: Enabled

=== START OF READ SMART DATA SECTION ===
SMART overall-health self-assessment test result: PASSED

General SMART Values:
Offline data collection status:  (0x00) Offline data collection activity
                    was never started.
                    Auto Offline Data Collection: Disabled.
Self-test execution status:      (   0) The previous self-test routine completed
                    without error or no self-test has ever 
                    been run.
Total time to complete Offline 
data collection:        (47804) seconds.
Offline data collection
capabilities:            (0x7b) SMART execute Offline immediate.
                    Auto Offline data collection on/off support.
                    Suspend Offline collection upon new
                    command.
                    Offline surface scan supported.
                    Self-test supported.
                    Conveyance Self-test supported.
                    Selective Self-test supported.
SMART capabilities:            (0x0003) Saves SMART data before entering
                    power-saving mode.
                    Supports SMART auto save timer.
Error logging capability:        (0x01) Error logging supported.
                    General Purpose Logging supported.
Short self-test routine 
recommended polling time:    (   2) minutes.
Extended self-test routine
recommended polling time:    ( 498) minutes.
Conveyance self-test routine
recommended polling time:    (   2) minutes.
SCT capabilities:          (0x3039) SCT Status supported.
                    SCT Error Recovery Control supported.
                    SCT Feature Control supported.
                    SCT Data Table supported.

SMART Attributes Data Structure revision number: 16
Vendor Specific SMART Attributes with Thresholds:
ID# ATTRIBUTE_NAME          FLAG     VALUE WORST THRESH TYPE      UPDATED  WHEN_FAILED RAW_VALUE
  1 Raw_Read_Error_Rate     0x002f   200   200   051    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
  3 Spin_Up_Time            0x0027   203   201   021    Pre-fail  Always       -       2808
  4 Start_Stop_Count        0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       58
  5 Reallocated_Sector_Ct   0x0033   200   200   140    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
  7 Seek_Error_Rate         0x002e   200   200   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
  9 Power_On_Hours          0x0032   064   064   000    Old_age   Always       -       26988
 10 Spin_Retry_Count        0x0032   100   253   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
 11 Calibration_Retry_Count 0x0032   100   253   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
 12 Power_Cycle_Count       0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       57
192 Power-Off_Retract_Count 0x0032   200   200   000    Old_age   Always       -       34
193 Load_Cycle_Count        0x0032   200   200   000    Old_age   Always       -       55
194 Temperature_Celsius     0x0022   102   091   000    Old_age   Always       -       45
196 Reallocated_Event_Count 0x0032   200   200   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
197 Current_Pending_Sector  0x0032   200   200   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
198 Offline_Uncorrectable   0x0030   100   253   000    Old_age   Offline      -       0
199 UDMA_CRC_Error_Count    0x0032   200   200   000    Old_age   Always       -       14
200 Multi_Zone_Error_Rate   0x0008   100   253   000    Old_age   Offline      -       0

SMART Error Log Version: 1
No Errors Logged

SMART Self-test log structure revision number 1
No self-tests have been logged.  [To run self-tests, use: smartctl -t]

SMART Selective self-test log data structure revision number 1
 SPAN  MIN_LBA  MAX_LBA  CURRENT_TEST_STATUS
    1        0        0  Not_testing
    2        0        0  Not_testing
    3        0        0  Not_testing
    4        0        0  Not_testing
    5        0        0  Not_testing
Selective self-test flags (0x0):
  After scanning selected spans, do NOT read-scan remainder of disk.
If Selective self-test is pending on power-up, resume after 0 minute delay.

sdd:
smartctl 7.1 2019-12-30 r5022 [x86_64-linux-4.18.0-553.16.1.el8_10.x86_64] (local build)
Copyright (C) 2002-19, Bruce Allen, Christian Franke, www.smartmontools.org

=== START OF INFORMATION SECTION ===
Model Family:     Seagate BarraCuda 3.5 (SMR)
Device Model:     ST4000DM004-2CV104
Serial Number:    [redacted]
LU WWN Device Id: 5 000c50 0e6b5caa4
Firmware Version: 0001
User Capacity:    4,000,787,030,016 bytes [4.00 TB]
Sector Sizes:     512 bytes logical, 4096 bytes physical
Rotation Rate:    5425 rpm
Form Factor:      3.5 inches
Device is:        In smartctl database [for details use: -P show]
ATA Version is:   ACS-3 T13/2161-D revision 5
SATA Version is:  SATA 3.1, 6.0 Gb/s (current: 3.0 Gb/s)
Local Time is:    Wed Sep 11 07:52:22 2024 EDT
SMART support is: Available - device has SMART capability.
SMART support is: Enabled

=== START OF READ SMART DATA SECTION ===
SMART overall-health self-assessment test result: PASSED

General SMART Values:
Offline data collection status:  (0x00) Offline data collection activity
                    was never started.
                    Auto Offline Data Collection: Disabled.
Self-test execution status:      (   0) The previous self-test routine completed
                    without error or no self-test has ever 
                    been run.
Total time to complete Offline 
data collection:        (    0) seconds.
Offline data collection
capabilities:            (0x73) SMART execute Offline immediate.
                    Auto Offline data collection on/off support.
                    Suspend Offline collection upon new
                    command.
                    No Offline surface scan supported.
                    Self-test supported.
                    Conveyance Self-test supported.
                    Selective Self-test supported.
SMART capabilities:            (0x0003) Saves SMART data before entering
                    power-saving mode.
                    Supports SMART auto save timer.
Error logging capability:        (0x01) Error logging supported.
                    General Purpose Logging supported.
Short self-test routine 
recommended polling time:    (   1) minutes.
Extended self-test routine
recommended polling time:    ( 495) minutes.
Conveyance self-test routine
recommended polling time:    (   2) minutes.
SCT capabilities:          (0x30a5) SCT Status supported.
                    SCT Data Table supported.

SMART Attributes Data Structure revision number: 10
Vendor Specific SMART Attributes with Thresholds:
ID# ATTRIBUTE_NAME          FLAG     VALUE WORST THRESH TYPE      UPDATED  WHEN_FAILED RAW_VALUE
  1 Raw_Read_Error_Rate     0x000f   082   064   006    Pre-fail  Always       -       175905729
  3 Spin_Up_Time            0x0003   097   097   000    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
  4 Start_Stop_Count        0x0032   100   100   020    Old_age   Always       -       11
  5 Reallocated_Sector_Ct   0x0033   100   100   010    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
  7 Seek_Error_Rate         0x000f   092   060   045    Pre-fail  Always       -       1504300167
  9 Power_On_Hours          0x0032   091   091   000    Old_age   Always       -       8367h+13m+54.995s
 10 Spin_Retry_Count        0x0013   100   100   097    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
 12 Power_Cycle_Count       0x0032   100   100   020    Old_age   Always       -       11
183 Runtime_Bad_Block       0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
184 End-to-End_Error        0x0032   100   100   099    Old_age   Always       -       0
187 Reported_Uncorrect      0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
188 Command_Timeout         0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0 0 0
189 High_Fly_Writes         0x003a   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
190 Airflow_Temperature_Cel 0x0022   059   056   040    Old_age   Always       -       41 (Min/Max 36/44)
191 G-Sense_Error_Rate      0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
192 Power-Off_Retract_Count 0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       77
193 Load_Cycle_Count        0x0032   099   099   000    Old_age   Always       -       2171
194 Temperature_Celsius     0x0022   041   044   000    Old_age   Always       -       41 (0 21 0 0 0)
195 Hardware_ECC_Recovered  0x001a   082   064   000    Old_age   Always       -       175905729
197 Current_Pending_Sector  0x0012   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
198 Offline_Uncorrectable   0x0010   100   100   000    Old_age   Offline      -       0
199 UDMA_CRC_Error_Count    0x003e   200   200   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
240 Head_Flying_Hours       0x0000   100   253   000    Old_age   Offline      -       7227h+36m+24.409s
241 Total_LBAs_Written      0x0000   100   253   000    Old_age   Offline      -       82275376008
242 Total_LBAs_Read         0x0000   100   253   000    Old_age   Offline      -       186020974325

SMART Error Log Version: 1
No Errors Logged

SMART Self-test log structure revision number 1
No self-tests have been logged.  [To run self-tests, use: smartctl -t]

SMART Selective self-test log data structure revision number 1
 SPAN  MIN_LBA  MAX_LBA  CURRENT_TEST_STATUS
    1        0        0  Not_testing
    2        0        0  Not_testing
    3        0        0  Not_testing
    4        0        0  Not_testing
    5        0        0  Not_testing
Selective self-test flags (0x0):
  After scanning selected spans, do NOT read-scan remainder of disk.
If Selective self-test is pending on power-up, resume after 0 minute delay.


Use hdparm -i  on both drives to see if the write cache is enabled.  Past that, they're not only different drives, they're different SMR drives.  They are likely to have wildly different performance characteristics.  The WD Red drive has a 180TB/yr, 3-year warranty, while the Barracuda has a 55TB, 2-year warranty.  To really quantify the performance experimentally, you may have to do a 4K random write benchmark of a section of each drive with fio.

They do both have write caching enabled.  I did actually have two WD Reds in that array (despite some recommendations against using the same make and model [and batch] disks in your array to mitigate a common cause failure of multiple drives at once) but one died very shortly (easily within the warranty period) after installing them, so based on that bad experience I replaced it with the Seagate Barracuda.  I can't even return the WD Red under warranty as it has confidential data on it and is damaged badly enough that I cannot wipe it to return it.  I encrypt those disks now due to that.
